# PIXI.js use colormatrix not for all child objects in stage

Tags: colormatrix, pixi.js

i'm using the colorMatrix Feature of PIXI.js library to randomly change the color of an image at runtime.Example: http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/examples/15/
This works fine, the Problem now is that the whole stage (including a text element) gets this color matrix and changes its color all the time. I want only the image to get this effect, not the text. I tried solving this by adding another stage and adding the text element to the new stage, but it didnt work. Let me know if you need a larger code snipped to understand the Problem.

Greez

Answer (score 0):

Color Matrices apply to the thing you add them to (stage, [container](http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/docs/classes/DisplayObjectContainer.html), etc) and all of the children. If you want the matrix to only apply to a certain subset of sprites, put those sprites in a container and add the matrix to that container (as a filter) as opposed to the stage as a whole.

Side note: If it's only one sprite and the color change is simple, you may want to use the tint property in the sprite class. It's just as easy to code and takes a lot less processing power (in my experience).